# UrlImageViewHelper - koush/ion how to install in xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-ion

Hi guys I was following a book about creating Xamarin.Android Apps, there is a reference to [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper), now it seems the project is deprecated in favor of [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), but the latter it's a gradle dependency for android native apps, how to use it within xamarin an visual studio 2017 ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: try https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Comment: I'll take a look ! thank you !